# POST successful but the data doesn't appear in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to post JSON data to the controller. 
The post is successful but the data is null.

This is the ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var result = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.ipdata.co/49.206.6.229?api-key=accesskey',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.city),
            console.log(data.latitude),
            console.log(data.longitude),
            result= { "city": data.city, "latitude":data.latitude, "longitude":data.longitude };

            debugger
            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/GeoLocation/GeoLocationData',
                data: result ,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data),
                    alert('Post Successful');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error');
                }  
            });
            debugger
        }
    });
});
```

I am getting the Post Successful alert, but am not able to use the data in the controller.

This is my controller Action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GeoLocationData(Location location)
{
    var city = location.city;
    var lat =  location.latitude;
    var lon =  location.longitude;
    return Ok();
}
```

My Model:

```
public class Location
{
    public String city { get; set; }

    [Column("latitude")] 
    public double? latitude { get; set; }

    [Column("longitude")]
    public double? longitude { get; set; }
}
```

This is the JSON data I am getting from the api:

```
data: { ...
   city: "xxxx", 
   continent_code: "xx" ,
   latitude: 17.3753, 
   longitude: 78.4744... }
```

When I inspect the debugger, I can see that the data is being passed correctly, however in the second ajax call though I have given

> data : result

, data takes the

> JSON response value

. Why is this so?

Comment: `GeoLocationData` does not return data. only HTTP STATUS 200 OK

Comment: try to use this class => `public class Location
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string continent_code { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}`

Comment: @Nkosi I was returning with the JSON result in the controller, still faced the same problem. Then I changed to status ok but the problem persists:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve data from body :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GeoLocationData([FromBody] Location location)
```

Answer (score 0):

On ajax request try this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(result),
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried the above , but still same problem, therefore reverted it back!!